# MvcMiniProfiler Unable to cast object of type EFProfiledDbConnection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I am trying to integrate MvcMiniProfiler  to my asp.net mvc+entity framewok project. Everything is ok for the first time web request but it is giving exception at the other requests.

My Project is
MVC 3
Entity Framework 4.1 (DatabaseFirst + POCO Generator DbContext)
MvcMiniProfiler.dll 1.9.0.0
MvcMiniProfiler.EntityFramework.dll 1.9.1.0
I install MvcMiniProfiler from Nu-Get

Added below to global.asax

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.Start();
            MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();       
        }
    }
```

Added below to web.config

```
   <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" />
      <add name="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" description="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" type="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProviderFactory, MvcMiniProfiler, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

I am getting this exception

```
    System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Connection(DbConnection value)
       at MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 118
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Connection(DbConnection value)
       at System.Data.Common.Utils.CommandHelper.SetStoreProviderCommandState(EntityCommand entityCommand, EntityTransaction entityTransaction, DbCommand storeProviderCommand)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
```

Exception is occured in EF calls

```
ModaEntitiesWrapper.GetInstance().Articles
               .AsNoTracking()
               .Where(p => p.StatusId == 1).ToList();
```

If I change version of MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider in Web.Config from 1.8.0.0 to 1.9.0.0
A new type of exception occured in MiniProfilerEF.Initialize() call.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.DataRowCollection.Remove(DataRow row)
       at MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfilerEF.Initialize()
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this will help. Move the `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();` to the top of the method `Application_Start()`. Note that in EF 4.1 and higher the method called should be `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42();` instead.

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    Logger.Info("Application start");
    MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Here's an example of how to use mvc-mini-profiler with EF Database First:

```
public static class Entities
{
    public static MyEntities Create()
    {
         var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString);
         var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ProviderConnectionString);
         var profiledConnection = new EFProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);

         return profiledConnection.CreateObjectContext<MyEntities>();
    }
}
```

You can then register your entities with an IOC container using the method or alternatively use something like

```
using(var entities = Entities.Create())
{
    //Do stuff here
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Edit: Forgot to add

> MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();

That is only used for EF Code First.

Comment: +1 Useful answer - just fixed a minor bug in your `Create` sample

Comment: I tried your solution but now I'm getting another exception like below
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection'.
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection connection) +613588
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +57
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +159

Comment: Hey Yucel, you need Entity Framework installed/referenced in your project and additional to MvcMiniProfiler -you also need the Entity Framework package. The EntityConnectionStringBuilder will parse the Entity Framework connection string with EF specific metadata. The ProviderConnectionString is the one we are used to (name, connectionString + provider). Internally in ADO.NET there is a factory with registered providers that instantiates the correct provider based on the provider attribute in the connection string. For example, MSSQL connections normally use the SqlClient provider.

Comment: profiledConnection.CreateObjectContext<T>() has a constraint to its generic type. It states that the type must be convertible to ObjectContext.
I think I'm missing the point here, the Entities class ìs the (generated) DbContext class, right? This does not inherit from ObjectContext (but is does implement IObjectContextAdapter). What I'm I overlooking?

Comment: @RobertSirre: I was able to get this working for EF 5 db-first by combining this answer with a call to the `CreateDbContext<T>()` method provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13498367/120955