# MiniProfiler and SQL Server Table Valued Parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, mvc-mini-profiler, table-valued-parameters

We use SQL Server for our database, and sometimes want to pass table valued parameters to stored procedures.

Our current method of doing this involves (C#):

```
// datatable is System.Data.DataTable
// command is System.Data.Common.DbCommand

var parameter = new SqlParameter("@Name", datatable); 
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
command.Paramaters.Add(parameter);
```

Where the stored procedure has parameter `@Name` of type `dbo.IdList` which is defined as follows

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NULL
)
```

this all works fine. However I'm unable to use this with MiniProfiler - I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Is there another way I can define and pass table valued parameters to stored procedures?

(Note: As well as the example above, we sometimes pass parameters where each row is a pair of ints)

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344777/mvcminiprofiler-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-efprofileddbconnection

Comment: And miniprofiler works fine for you if you are using a more standard sql query?

Comment: Unfortunately my application uses one of these queries every time and there's no easy way to separate it. I've got it working for the non-SQL stuff.